# How to install Selenium RC?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

I went to download page of Selenium RC and
downloaded file "selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0 jar". Copied it to D:
and then ran below command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar
```

I get Unable to access jarfile selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar error
How can I install Selenium RC? I already installed the plug-in in FF for Selenium IDE.

Also what should be next once I have RC installed successfully? How do I
verify if RC has been installed properly?

Answer (score 2):

You don't install RC, you run it from the command line using the `java -jar <jarname>` command like you specified.

In your case, you probably need to run your command prompt as administrator in order to start the server. You could also change the jar file permissions to allow it to run without an elevated prompt.

In any case, you will need to setup a project in the language of your choice and either record and then export from IDE, or write your own tests from scratch.

This tutorial may help you get started: http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=17

It is also worth noting that RC is a deprecated technology, and you should really consider using WebDriver if that is an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run the Selenium server at all. Since you're new to Selenium what i would suggest is that you download and install Eclipse, if you're doing this in Java, start a new project and the jar file to your build path.

Take a look at the link below

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Skip over the Maven part, simply install Eclipse, create a new project, add the jar to the build path (project properties -> build paths) copy the example and run it. This should give you a pretty good idea of how selenium webdriver works. Unless you're already familiar with tools like maven, testng, junit, ant, etc i would stay away from them until you get a better grasp on Selenium then work your way to those tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to command line and type in 'java -version' do you get the version of jave listed? If not, then you need to update your environment variables to tell it where the executable for java is (you will likely need to do that for the browsers that you want to use too).

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

also, you'll need to provide the exact path to the '.jar' file so if you have it/inside/a/folder/ you'll need to tell it where in your command :)